# I want to build my first computer but don't have the time. Where could I learn about the different components and how they work?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, mac, router, hardware-rec

I want to learn about how computers work, and maybe eventually routers, but don't have the time right now to build one. Could someone point me in the direction of what the different hardware components are and give links so I could get a good preview? Tutorials would be fantastic. I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

I'm thinking I'm going to build a windows 7 or windows 8 gaming computer. Is that a good idea for a first computer?

Comment: There's only a bazillion books on this subject. Try here - http://www.quepublishing.com/imprint/series_detail.aspx?ser=335234

Comment: This is a Q & A Site, Not a teaching website.

Comment: An interesting place to start would be here: http://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/wiki/builds , be prepared to do some googling because you will want to know what the different terms you come across mean.

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.com/ is the goto site for these kinds of questions. It's all about building stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
Newegg has a series of videos explaining some basic details about different components, but it's more about walking through a build than explaining what the components do and how they interact.
Here: http://www.newegg.com/Computer-Hardware/Store

the videos are in the middle of the page.

More time-consuming method:
Get your hands on a comptia a+ study manual and read it. It will take longer, but you'll have a more thorough (and especially windows-based) understanding of how the pc works and some networking technology as well. It's basic, but a good place to start.

I expect I'll some hatred here about the mention of a+...

If you're trying to get a quick view into the idea of a pc build, I recommend the newegg videos.

Final note:
the operating system (win7, win8, a linux distro...) wouldn't determine the overall build, but a basic gaming pc running windows (and/or Ubuntu Linux now that Steam is available on it. I have a friend who plays nothing but Borderlands 2 from Steam on a gaming laptop running ubuntu) would definitely be a good first project because you'll have to do some research and even a basic gaming rig will more than likely contain all of the same components (albeit at a lower price and/or performance) as you'd see in many other types of builds later on as you get more advanced.

Comment: Why's this being downvoted?

Comment: The question or the answer?

Comment: @Ramhound either way, it was a trigger-happy answer. Agree with being put on hold for the stated reasons.